# How to upload a file using HTTP connector with content type multipart/form data in mulesoft

Tags: java, mule, anypoint-studio

I am trying to upload a file(multipart/form data) in Jira using mule. I got 200 as status but it gives empty response and no file is uploaded into Jira. The file content is in Buffered inputstream.

```
 <set-attachment attachmentName="#[flowVars.filename]" value="#[payload]" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="Attachment" metadata:id="2d991254-c66e-4861-b099-eb624ea4a018"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/rest/api/2/issue/JIR-2/attachments" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="oauth_nonce" value="#[flowVars.para.oauth_nonce]"/>
            <http:query-param paramName="oauth_token" value="#[flowVars.para.oauth_token]"/>
            <http:query-param paramName="oauth_timestamp" value="#[flowVars.para.oauth_timestamp]"/>
            <http:query-param paramName="oauth_signature_method" value="RSA-SHA1"/>
            <http:query-param paramName="oauth_consumer_key" value="hardcoded-consumer"/>
            <http:query-param paramName="oauth_version" value="1.0"/>
            <http:query-param paramName="oauth_signature" value="#[flowVars.para.oauth_signature]"/>
            <http:header headerName="X-Atlassian-Token" value="nocheck"/>
            <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"/>
            <http:header headerName="------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW Content-Disposition" value="form-data; name=&quot;documentFile&quot;; filename=&quot;documentFile&quot;"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you are using HTTP for processing the file , the best option is "mule requester", you can use this to call a file in mid of your mule flow.so try that you will a sort idea for your problem